# How can query the unique latest entries from a range based on an ID and a timestamp column (D)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I have these rows below returned from the data set at the top?

[image]

I've started something with `=SORT(SORTN(QUERY(A1:E4; "select *");9^9;2;4;1);4;1)` but it gives me the wrong result.
Here is [the file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way

```
=MAP(UNIQUE(E1:E4);LAMBDA(id;XLOOKUP(id;E1:E4;A1:E4;;;-1)))
```

We are using XLOOKUP to look up the ids and return the row corresponding to the latest match.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
={A1:E1;sortn(sort(A2:E4;4;0);9^9;2;5;1)}
```

[image]